# How to call @layout from public directory

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know how can I call the blade directives such as `@extends('layouts.app')`, `@section('title', 'Enquiries')` and `@section('content')` , from the public directory. I'm manually working on some core php files and i would like to implement the blade directives. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Not quite clear what you're trying to do here

Comment: if you working in a normal php file, that is impossible. They are related to blade.

Comment: Laravel uses `resources/views` directory for this. Your index.php file is only a connector to the blades and the eloquent system. First you have to read [Directory Structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but if you're trying to use blade templates outside of Laravel, you can use the [jenssegers/blade](https://github.com/jenssegers/blade) package.

Install with:

```
composer require jenssegers/blade
```

Usage:

```
use Jenssegers\Blade\Blade;

$blade = new Blade('views', 'cache');
echo $blade->make('homepage', ['name' => 'John Doe']);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.